# Collect the SKETCH NAME in the array and hunt for matching CUSTOME PROPERTY NAME and apply TOLERANCE (Bilateral or Symmetric)

Tags: vba, solidworks

I want to apply a tolerance value to my sketch using a custom property, the input for which will be provided as JSON

Here I tried to collect the sketch name from the specific feature (i.e ISO Standard Feature) from the Solidworks feature tree. [image]

Once the feature is available, `GetDispDimension` collects all the names available in the sketch and stores them in an array.

```
Sub GetDispDimension()

        Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
        Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
        Set swPart = swModel
        
        'Hunt for sketch name in the feature tree
        SKETCH_NAME = "ISO Standard"
        
        Set swFeat = swPart.FeatureByName(SKETCH_NAME)
        Set swDispDim = swFeat.GetFirstDisplayDimension
    
        i = 0
        Do While Not swDispDim Is Nothing
            Set swDim = swDispDim.GetDimension2(1)
            
            vDimVals = swDim.GetValue3(swThisConfiguration, Empty)
            'Debug.Print swDim.Name & "@" & SKETCH_NAME & ": " & Round(vDimVals(0), 6)
            Set swDispDim = swFeat.GetNextDisplayDimension(swDispDim)
            swDimName = swDim.Name
            swDimNameArr(i) = UCase(swDimName)
            'Debug.Print swDim.Name & "**** Debug"'
            Debug.Print " Dimension Name : " & i & " : " & swDimNameArr(i)
            
            'if sketch name have TOL_Min then hunt for matching custom property
            If InStr(1, swDimNameArr(i), "TOL_MIN", vbTextCompare) Then
                Call GetCustomProperty
            Else
                Debug.Print "NOT FOUND"
            End If
        i = i + 1
        Loop
End Sub
```

`GetCustomProperty` applies tolerance, either open or bilaterial, based on the `TOL_MIN` and `TOL_MAX` dimensions

```
Sub GetCustomProperty()

    Dim j As Integer
    
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set swPart = swModel
    Set swSelMgr = swModel.SelectionManager
    Set swDimension = swDispDim.GetDimension2(0)
    Set swDimensionTolerance = swDimension.Tolerance

    swCustInfoNameArr = swModel.GetCustomInfoNames2("")
    
        'For Each Custom property Name In swDimNameArr
        j = 0
            swCustInfoNameArr = swCustInfoNameArr(j) 'UCase(CustName)
            
            Do While j < UBound(swCustInfoNameArr)
                Debug.Print "Custom Property Name : "; j & " : " & UCase(swCustInfoNameArr(j))
                If InStr(1, swCustInfoNameArr(j), "TOL_MIN", vbTextCompare) Then
                    Debug.Print swDimNameArr(i)
                    
                  ' Get the custom property data
                  maxValue = swCustProp.Get4(CustName, False, val, valout)
                  MaxTolValue = valout
                    
                  'convertion to metric unit
                  MaxTolValueMetric = MaxTolValue / 1000
                  Debug.Print "Maximum Tolerance value: " & MaxTolValue
                  MsgBox MaxTolValue
                  
                  'Set tolerance type to fit with tolerance and transitional
                  swDimensionTolerance.Type = swTolType_e.swTolBILAT
                  Debug.Print "Type of tolerance (8 = swTolType_e.swTolBILAT): " & swDimensionTolerance.Type
                  swDimensionTolerance.FitType = swFitType_e.swFitTRANSITIONAL
                    Debug.Print "Type of fit tolerance (2 = swFitType_e.swFitTransitional): " & swDimensionTolerance.FitType
                    Debug.Print ""
                    
                Else
                    Debug.Print "NOT MATCHED"
                End If
                j = j + 1
            Loop
            'Exit For
    
        For Each CustName In swCustInfoNameArr
        CustName = UCase(CustName)
        Debug.Print "Custom Property Name : " & CustName
        
                    
            ' Get the custom property data
            Set swCustProp = swModelDocExt.CustomPropertyManager("")
            minValue = swCustProp.Get4(CustName, False, val, valout)
            MinTolValue = valout
            
            'Selected dimension name containing Max_TOL
            If InStr(1, CustName, "TOL_MAX", vbTextCompare) Then
                  
                  'convertion to metric unit
                  MaxTolValueMetric = MaxTolValue / 1000
                  Debug.Print "Maximum Tolerance value: " & MaxTolValue
                  MsgBox MaxTolValue
                  'Debug.Print "Value:                    " & val
                  Debug.Print "Evaluated value:          " & valout
    
            ElseIf InStr(1, CustName, "TOL_MIN", vbTextCompare) Then
                    
                  'convertion to metric unit
                  MinTolValueMetric = MinTolValue / 1000
                  Debug.Print "Minimum Tolerance value: " & MinTolValue
                  MsgBox MinTolValue
                  'Debug.Print "Value:                    " & val
                  Debug.Print "Evaluated value:          " & valout
                              
                If MaxTolValue = MinTolValue Then
                    ' Select the Symmetric tolerance
                    'Set tolerance type to fit with tolerance
                    swDimensionTolerance.Type = swTolType_e.swTolSYMMETRIC
                    Debug.Print "Type of tolerance (8 = swTolType_e.swTolSYMMETRIC): " & swDimensionTolerance.Type
                    swDimensionTolerance.FitType = swFitType_e.swFitTRANSITIONAL
                    Debug.Print "Type of fit tolerance (2 = swFitType_e.swFitTransitional): " & swDimensionTolerance.FitType
                    Debug.Print ""
              
                Else
                    ' Select the Bilateral tolerance
                    'Set tolerance type to fit with tolerance and transitional
                    swDimensionTolerance.Type = swTolType_e.swTolBILAT
                    Debug.Print "Type of tolerance (8 = swTolType_e.swTolBILAT): " & swDimensionTolerance.Type
                    swDimensionTolerance.FitType = swFitType_e.swFitTRANSITIONAL
                    Debug.Print "Type of fit tolerance (2 = swFitType_e.swFitTransitional): " & swDimensionTolerance.FitType
                    Debug.Print ""
                End If
            
                ' Set new dimension tolerance values
                Status = swDimensionTolerance.SetValues2(MinTolValueMetric, MaxTolValueMetric, swSetValueInConfiguration_e.swSetValue_InThisConfiguration, swTolType_e.swTolBILAT)
                Debug.Print (" Maximum dimension tolerance: " & swDimensionTolerance.SetValues(MinTolValueMetric, MaxTolValueMetric))
                'Debug.Print (" Minimum dimension tolerance: " & swDimensionTolerance.SetValues(MinTolValue / 1000, 0))
    
                'Get some dimension tolerance values
                fontHeight = swDimensionTolerance.GetFontHeight
                Debug.Print ("  Height of font: " & fontHeight * 1000# & " mm")
                fontScale = swDimensionTolerance.GetFontScale
                Debug.Print ("  Scale of font: " & fontScale)
                Debug.Print ""
        
              Else
                  Debug.Print (" Tolerance cannot be applied to this dimension ")
              End If
    
          'Else
          '    Debug.Print ("Dimension name and custom property didnt match")
          'End If
        
      Next
      
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this code work? Code review is only for working code.

Comment: Hello HackSlash, Yes, this code is working perfectly.